# convert jena model to jena tdb

Tags: java, query-optimization, rdf, jena

I created a model in jena with this java code

```
    Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    Resource a1 = m.createResource("<http://Actor1>");
    Resource a2 = m.createResource("<http://Actor2>");
    Resource a3 = m.createResource("<http://Actor3>");
    Property p3 = m.createProperty("<http://MovieTitle>");

    Resource m1 = m.createResource("<http://Movie1>");
    m1.addProperty(p3, "<http://M1>");
    Resource m2 = m.createResource("<http://Movie2>");
    m2.addProperty(p3, "<http://M2>");
    Resource m3 = m.createResource("<http://Movie3>");
    m3.addProperty(p3, "<http://M3>");
    Resource m4 = m.createResource("<http://Movie4>");
    m4.addProperty(p3, "<http://M4>");

    Property p1 = m.createProperty("<http://dateOfbirth>");
    Property p2 = m.createProperty("<http://played>");

    m.add(a1,p1 , "1980");
    m.add(a2,p1 , "1981");
    m.add(a3,p1 , "1982");

    m.add(a1,p2 , m1);
    m.add(a1,p2 , m2);
    m.add(a1,p2 , m3);
    m.add(a1,p2 , m4);
    m.add(a2,p2 , m1);
    m.add(a2,p2 , m3);
    m.add(a3,p2 , m1);
    m.add(a3,p2 , m3);
    m.add(a3,p2 , m4);
```

now i want to convert this model into a jena tdb to create the stats.opt file for optimizing queries executed over this model. I know that rdf files can be loaded into tdb and create stats.opt using the command line. but i want to do it with my code. Is there a way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: It will need data a lot bigger before stats.opt has any effect. It will only be a factor in performance in 10's, usually 100's, of millions of triples. The StatsCollector, StatsResults and Stats (to write the file format) classes are the ones used.  See the code for tdbstats. While you can calculate stats on any data, a TDB database only looks for the stats information when attaching to the data the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your tdb in jena using -->

```
// First create an empty tdb 
Dataset tdb = TDBFactory.createDataset(path2NewTdb);

// Then get its Model
Model tdbModel = tdb.getDefaultModel();

// Then update tdbModel. For example use the code you wrote
// above or if you already have a model use tdbModel.add(anotherModel)
// After that make sure to close everything

tdbModel.close();
tdb.close();
```